# Prevent Google Chrome from using local fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using the Raleway font on my website but unless I have the font installed on my local desktop, it does not display properly. Specifically, the weight is always bold. I've had others report this as well. From what I can tell it's because Google is trying to use my desktop fonts for performance but is there any way to prevent this on my site with either CSS or JS? A solution that wouldn't involve changing browser settings. What's strange is that the fonts are displaying properly on Googles Font library. and yes, I see this issue on other websites that us the Raleway font.

[image: This is what I'm seeing]

[image: And this is what I'm suppose to be seeing.]

Comment: Have you declared that font with `@font-face` CSS rule?

Comment: Yes, it's Google Fonts: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700.

Comment: Short answer: you don't want to. For your website, you want to know that *everyone* who accesses the page sees the same font, and there is *no* guarantee that if someone has Lato installed locally, it's the same version you're using for your website. So don't try to make an exception for yourself: you are just another user, operate under that assumption.

Comment: I'm not sure the relevance of your comment? I understand what you're saying, but I am noting my issue as a user? And the issue is occurring the user does not have the Raleway font installed on their computer.

Comment: My understanding is that the OP was asking for a browser setting, not about a CSS trick.

Answer (score 1):

The default Google Font APIs include `src: local(<font>)`, which causes the browser to look for the local files before downloading the web font. If you really want to prevent this, you can create your own `@font-face` declarations and omit the `local` directives. Use something like the Google Web Font Loader to get the appropriate `@font-face` declaration, as the Google Font APIs only return the font files for your specific browser and I assume you want to be compatible with all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing just the bold style for Raleway? Check that you have 400 (normal) on the import URL for the font. Should look something like this:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700
```

(that gives you normal and bold)

Comment: Nevermind, just saw your comment above, so you are. :/

Answer (score 0):

It is because you do not select desired font-weight.  If you inspect that google css file  [fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700) you see that last @font-face have font-weight: 700;.  In css last @font-face takes precedence over prior definitions. If you do not specify exact font-weight, browser will choose its default - in your example it is bold (700) because it is defined last.